# representing text data as numerical data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| struct_1 | AA |
| struct_bent_22 | AA |
| sound_1 | BB |
| sound_type_1 | BB |

I want to represent col_1 as numbers in a way that it retains the variability of the text. Any suggestions on how to do this ? If this is not a good idea, then any suggestions would be helpful.

expected output:

| col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | AA |
| 1233 | AA |
| 12345 | BB |
| 123456 | BB |

Those numbers obviously do not capture what the text means, but I need a solution that captures the features of the text. (If possible)

Comment: So you want unique IDs for `struct_1`, `struct_bent_22`, etc? And you also want them to be the same number even if you add new strings to that list?

Comment: I have made the edits to the post. Please take a look.

Comment: I _think_ my answer that I just undeleted does what you want.

Comment: " but I need a solution that captures the features of the text. " *what does that mean exactly*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While hashing always involves the risk of collision, I might look at:

```py
import hashlib

def str_to_int(text):
    return int(hashlib.sha256(text.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest(), 16)

print(str_to_int("struct_1"))
print(str_to_int("struct_bent_22"))
```

and see if that works for you.

it should give you:

```
67086348026381773031976814245037562760713897031875549849861239415057698757195
24493846661393758293236341956602133508998612831345007873168413426300746343739
```